# Component communication in Knockout.JS

Tags: knockout.js, custom-component

I am desiging a "medium" sized application in KnockoutJS and I am wondering how to send events between components.

Imagined a nested component hierarchy in KnockoutJS:

```
Root Viewmodel -> A -> B -> C
               -> D
```

How can D react to a message from C? The obvious knockoutJS approach would be to have C write to an observable passed as a parameter, and share this observable with D which reacts to changes to this observable.

What I do not like about this approach is, that A and B need to know about the message, and A and B actively forward the handler via its parameters. With a normal dependency Inject approach I could wire up the components C and D directly with each other, e.g. by injecting D into C without A and B knowing.

So my question:

- Is there a way to manually wire up the components inside the root viewmodel (e.g. by intercepting component creation)?

or rephrased:

- How can I configure a nested component from the main viewmodel without going through its parent component?

```js
ko.components.register("aaa", {
    viewModel: function (params) { this.handler = params.handler;  },
    template: "<span>A</span> <bbb params='handler: handler'></bbb>"
});

ko.components.register("bbb", {
    viewModel: function (params) { this.handler = params.handler;  },
    template: "<span>B</span> <ccc params='handler: handler'></ccc>"
});

ko.components.register("ccc", {
    viewModel: function (params) { this.handler = params.handler;  },
    template: "<span>C</span> <button data-bind='click: handler'>OK</button>"
});

ko.components.register("ddd", {
    viewModel: function (params) { 
        var self = this; 
        this.text = ko.observable("No event received!"); 
        if (params.onClick)     params.onClick.subscribe(function () {
            self.text("Event Received!");
        });
    },
    template: "<span>D</span> <span data-bind='text:text'/>"
});


ko.applyBindings({
    onClick: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p><aaa params='handler: onClick'> </aaa></p>
<p><ddd params='onClick: onClick'> </ddd></p>
```

Comment: Have you considered a pattern as used in the [knockout postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox#knockout-postbox) plugin?

Comment: How would you ideally define in `ccc` how to access the method from `aaa`? By naming convention? You could create some sort of shared params component loader, but implementing how you'd dynamically find the right param inside `ccc` is still a challenge... Anyway, here's how you "intercent component creation": https://jsfiddle.net/r7zt4rf9/

Comment: Perfect - After all whoever wires up components ccc and ddd needs to know specifics about both. I was trying to get the component loader code right, but failed with trying to hook the component constructor by using the default component loader. This way the main view model can get a handle on any ccc or ddd component that is created. What it does with it is up to the application. This will solve my problem. If you put that code in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer that includes some additional explanation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to manually wire up the components inside the root viewmodel (e.g. by **intercepting component creation**)?
>
> <sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>

### The knockout mechanism

You can inject [custom component loaders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html) by adding an object to the `ko.components.loaders` array with any combination of the methods `getConfig`, `loadComponent`, `loadTemplate`, and `loadViewModel`.

Since you're looking to create a connection between view models, this is the only method we need to define. From the docs:

> `loadViewModel(name, viewModelConfig, callback)`
>
> The viewModelConfig value is simply the viewModel property from any componentConfig object. For example, it may be a constructor function, ...

### The approach

Your components are defined referencing a constructor function directly. We're going to wrap this constructor in a factory function that replaces the `params` passed to the component, by a joined `sharedParams` object that holds everything that's passed to any component up the chain. **Whether this is "safe" enough is up to you.** It shouldn't be too hard to come up with another way of connecting `aaa` and `ddd` once you got the custom loader in place.

In short, our custom loader will:

1. Retrieve the original constructor for the component's viewmodel (`VM`)
2. Dynamically create a `factory` function that:

   - Adds the passed `params` to the binding context
   - Construct the `VM` instance with the *shared* params
   - returns the new viewmodel
3. Call the newly created `factory` function

In code:

```
ko.components.loaders.unshift({
  loadViewModel: function loadViewModel(name, VM, callback) {
    const factory = function (params, componentInfo) {
      const bc = ko.contextFor(componentInfo.element);

      // Overwrite sharedParams
      bc.sharedParams = Object.assign(
        { },
        bc.sharedParams || {},
        params
      );

      return new VM(bc.sharedParams);
    };

    return callback(factory);
  }
});
```

### Running example

Check out this linked fiddle to play with the custom loader yourself. I've included several nested component structures to show there's no longer the need to pass the `params` manually.

https://jsfiddle.net/sqLathu9/

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I personally find quite ugly, but *can* be considered a valid answer to this question:

You can use `$root`, `$parents[i]` or `$parent` to refer to any layer in the binding context of a component. I removed some of the `params` from your example to show you how this would work. It shows two flavors:

1. Get a dependency from the `bindingContext` inside the `params` attribute (preferred)
2. Access the `bindingContext` *inside* the component template (not recommended)

```js
ko.components.register("aaa", {
    viewModel: function (params) {  },
    template: "<span>A</span> <bbb></bbb>"
});

ko.components.register("bbb", {
    viewModel: function (params) {  },
    template: "<span>B</span> <ccc></ccc>"
});

ko.components.register("ccc", {
    viewModel: function (params) { },
    // This hides the dependency in the template. It's better to pass it in the DOM via `params`
    template: "<span>C</span> <button data-bind='click: $root.onClick'>OK</button>"
});

ko.components.register("ddd", {
    viewModel: function (params) { 
        var self = this; 
        this.text = ko.observable("No event received!"); 
        if (params.onClick)     params.onClick.subscribe(function () {
            self.text("Event Received!");
        });
    },
    template: "<span>D</span> <span data-bind='text:text'/>"
});


ko.applyBindings({
    onClick: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p><aaa> </aaa></p>
<!-- This approach isn't *that* ugly, since the dependency is made explicit in the DOM -->
<p><ddd params='onClick: $root.onClick'> </ddd></p>
```

The weakness here is that you create a fixed dependency on the DOM structure that is hard to document/check. I usually start running in to bugs as soon as I use `$parent`...

Comment: I think the big problem here is, that component C needs to know the receiver of the message, which violates the idea of components in the first place. Making the component work only when a onClick property exists at the ROOT view model is a bad solution for all but very small projects.

Answer (score 0):

In that case of scenarios I think it's better to use EventEmitter https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter

This way you can create a global `ee` instance of `EventEmitter` for example in a script on your main html

`window.ee = new EventEmitter()`

then you can add listeners or trigger actions between components:

as for your example from component C you can trigger an event with: `window.ee.emitEvent('some-name-for-the-event', someArgumentsArray)`

and in your D component just add a listener for that event to react accordingly like `window.ee.addListener('some-name-for-the-event', function (params) { 
    // your own code to handle the event 
});`

Comment: Using window is not a good solution (think about unit test scenarios), although of course I could stick a global variable everywhere of cause. In any way this way I would hook up ALL components to the same event emitter. Like in the postbox plugin (which uses a global variable on the knockout library). The question is - is there a way to wire up only the two components without introducing a shared state between all components. For this one would need to get a handle to the nested child component from the main view model. But how?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is when D is created by C, C passes a parameter as a reference to D, and D assigns itself to this parameter. The param can be an observable, and the onDispose of D can clear the observable so that C knows if D was disposed.